# ascii function in oracle sql, for non-ascii value

Tags: oracle, non-ascii-characters

In Oracle SQL:

When we pass any non-ascii characters to ascii function, it is returning some number. How we can interpret that number. If we have character set as AL32UTF8, why its not returning Unicode point for given character

```
select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';--AL32UTF8

select ascii('Á') from dual;--50049
```

what is the meaning of this value 50049?  I was expecting 193

Comment: Good question. `dump()` applied to your accented A does, indeed, return 50049; the `ascii()` function just reports what is stored. If you give Á as being in the **national** character set, for example with `n'Á'`, as the argument to `ascii()`, you will get the expected return value. If you need to do this on expressions, not on text literals, you can wrap the expression within `to_nchar()` and you will again get the expected result. None of this explains why Oracle stores the character as value 50049 (decimal) in character set UTF-8 though.

Comment: More thoughts. Who knows what the AL32UTF8 encoding is; whatever it is, apparently it does encode the accented A as decimal 50049. (You can, for example, select CHR(50049) and it will return the right character; CHR(193) will not.) The reason you expect 193 is because that is the **code point** of the letter in the Unicode coded character set. It just happens that for two-byte characters, UTF16 encoded value is just the code point itself. Not so in UTF8. So, if you expect to get the code point rather than the encoding, you will find more luck with UTF16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here - mostly for my own education - is an explanation of the value 50049 for the accented A (code point: 193 in the Unicode coded character set). I just learned how this works, from reading https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm  Another pretty clear explanation and an example for a three-byte encoding on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding

The computation of the encoding is derived from the code point 193 and has nothing to do with which specific character is associated with that code point.

UTF-8 uses a relatively simple scheme to encode code points up to 1,141,111 (or, likely, more these days; for now let's only worry about code points up to that upper limit).

Code points from 1 to 127 (decimal) are encoded as a single byte, equal to the code point (so the byte always has a leading zero when represented in binary).

Code points from 128 to 2047 are encoded as two bytes. The first byte, in binary representation, always begins with 110, and the second with 10. A byte that begins with 110 is always the first byte of a two-byte encoding, and a byte that begins with 10 is always a "continuation" byte (second, third or fourth) in a multi-byte encoding. These mandatory prefixes are part of the encoding scheme (the "rules" of UTF8 encoding); they are hard-coded values in the rules.

So: for code points from 128 to 2047, the encoding is in two bytes, of the exact format 110xxxxx and 10xxxxxx in binary notation. The last five digits (bits) from the first byte, plus the last six digits from the second (total: 11 bits) are the binary representation of the code point (the value from 128 to 2047 that must be encoded).

2047 = 2^11 - 1 (this is why 2047 is relevant here). The code point can be represented as an 11-bit binary number (possibly with leading zeros). Take the first five bits (after left-padding with 0 to a length of 11 bits) and attach that to the mandatory 110 prefix of the first byte, and take the last six bits of the code point and attach them to the mandatory prefix 10 of the second byte. That gives the UTF8 encoding (in two bytes) of the given code point.

Let's do that for code point 193(decimal). In binary, and padding with 0 to the left, that is 00011000001. So far, nothing fancy.

Split this into five bits || six bits: 00011 and 000001.

Attach the mandatory prefixes:  **110**00011 and **10**000001.

Rewrite these in hex:  \xC3 and \x81.  Put them together; this is hex C381, or decimal 50049.

Comment: Unicode specifies 1.114.112 code points, UTF-8 is able to encode all of them and theoretically would support even more. However, UTF-16 is limited to 1.114.112 code points, that's the reason for the current range. As of today around 140.000 code points are allocated, so there is still much space left for new alphabets and languages.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Right - I know also that the upper bound is not set in stone. In any case, there should be no confusion for "standard" characters (letters from various alphabets, for example). My interest in this answer (as I am learning how the encoding scheme works, for the first time) was in the translation between code points and encodings, and back in the other direction; which code points are valid in Unicode - that, I wasn't too interested in (at this time).

Comment: Gotcha!!!! so basically it is combing all hex after UTF-8 encoding. And converting the combined hex to decimal. select to_number('C381', 'XXXX') from dual; --50049

Comment: @shobhit - To be very precise (pedantic) here: you asked why the `ascii` function doesn't return the Unicode point of the character. I don't know if you meant this literally; "point" is 100% a technical term. The "code point" of Á in Unicode is 193. But the `ascii` function does not return the code point - it returns the encoded value, in the database encoding (UTF8). Especially if you were around in the days of "code pages", all this business of "code point" and "encoding" as different things may be quite confusing. But the discussion, then, is no longer about `ascii` (or SQL, or computing).

Answer (score 1):

See documentation: [ASCII](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions014.htm#SQLRF00604)

> `ASCII` returns the decimal representation in the database character set of the first character of char.

Binary value of character `Á` (U+00C1) in UTF-8 is `xC381` which is decimal 50049.

193 is the Code Point. For UTF-8 the code point is equal to binary representation only for characters U+0000 - U+007F (0-127) . For UTF-16BE the code point is equal to binary representation only for characters U+0000 - U+FFFF (0-65535),

Maybe you are looking for

```
ASCIISTR('Á')
```

which returns `\00C1`, you only have to convert it to a decimal value.

Some time ago I developed this function, which is more advanced than `ASCIISTR`, it works also work multicode characters.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);


FUNCTION UNICODECHAR(uchar VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE IS

    UTF16 VARCHAR2(32000) := ASCIISTR(uchar);
    UTF16_Table VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE := VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE();
    sg1 VARCHAR2(4);
    sg2 VARCHAR2(4);
    codepoint INTEGER;

    res VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE := VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE();
    i INTEGER;
BEGIN
 
    IF uchar IS NULL THEN
        RETURN VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE();
    END IF;
    
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(UTF16, '(\\[[:xdigit:]]{4})|.', 1, LEVEL)
    BULK COLLECT INTO UTF16_Table  
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(UTF16, '\\[[:xdigit:]]{4}|.', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
    
    i := UTF16_Table.FIRST;
    WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
        res.EXTEND;
        IF REGEXP_LIKE(UTF16_Table(i), '^\\') THEN
            IF REGEXP_LIKE(UTF16_Table(i), '^\\D(8|9|A|B)') THEN
                sg1 := REGEXP_SUBSTR(UTF16_Table(i), '[[:xdigit:]]{4}');
                i := UTF16_Table.NEXT(i);
                sg2 := REGEXP_SUBSTR(UTF16_Table(i), '[[:xdigit:]]{4}');
                codepoint := 2**10 * (TO_NUMBER(sg1, 'XXXX') - TO_NUMBER('D800', 'XXXX')) + TO_NUMBER(sg2, 'XXXX') - TO_NUMBER('DC00', 'XXXX') + 2**16;
                res(res.LAST) := 'U+'||TO_CHAR(codepoint, 'fmXXXXXX');
            ELSE
                res(res.LAST) := 'U+'||REGEXP_REPLACE(UTF16_Table(i), '^\\');
            END IF; 
        ELSE
            res(res.LAST) := 'U+'||LPAD(TO_CHAR(ASCII(UTF16_Table(i)), 'fmXX'), 4, '0');
        END IF;     
        i := UTF16_Table.NEXT(i);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN res;

END UNICODECHAR;
```

Try some examples from https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f3f3_fe0f_200d_1f308

```
UNICODECHAR('‍☠️')
```

should return

```
U+1F3F4 
U+200D 
U+2620 
U+FE0F
```

Comment: When you say "code point ... equal to *decimal*", what do you mean by "decimal"? That should be "encoding" (encoded value) - and, indeed, it's independent of base - whether binary, decimal, octal, hex or anything else, is it not?

Comment: OK, I see the edit, but I don't think it cures the problem. The binary representation *of what*? The comparison is between "code point" and "encoding" - and that distinction has nothing to do with the numeral system.

Comment: @mathguy how would you express it? Maybe "the code point is equal to the encoded value"? I guess it is clear what I like to say.

Comment: I believe the technical term is "encoding" - and adding "encoded value" in parentheses will make it clearer still. Unfortunately "encoding" has at least two technical meanings in this context - one refers to the overall scheme, while the other refers to individual characters - so I so understand your hesitation. "UTF-8 encoding" is the overall scheme; "UTF-8 encoding of the dollar sign character" refers to the encoding of a single character.